# Library or API for file browser view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like to implement a file browser view in my application so users can open files using a side panel similar to the browsers in XCode, Text Wrangler and some other programs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Before I go off implementing another one of those browsers from scratch, does anyone know if there are existing libraries or APIs that already does this?

Google doesn't turn up with much and most of the searches point me to [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which I believe doesn't do what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cocoa class that is used to display hierarchical lists is called [NSOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
Outline views provide several configuration options to adjust the appearance. 
The content can be provided by implementing a [data source protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSOutlineViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSOutlineViewDataSource) or via Cocoa bindings.

Apple has some sample code online that should get you started (it's a file browser - so maybe you can use larger parts of that sample):
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html